# C++/CLI .ToString() returning error

Tags: c++-cli

I am a beginner to C++/CLI as I come from a C# background.  I am currently writing a wrapper for some native C++ code.  I have the following methods:

```
    void AddToBlockList(System::String^ address)
    {
        char* cAddress = (char*)(void*)Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(address);
        _packetFilter->AddToBlockList(cAddress);
    }

    void AddToBlockList(IPAddress^ address)
    {
        char* cAddress = (char*)(void*)Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(address.ToString());
        _packetFilter->AddToBlockList(cAddress);
    }
```

...The first method works fine and converts my string into the character array.  However, the second function with the IPAddress object as the signiture gives me the following error:

> ```
> error C2228: left of '.ToString' must have class/struct/union
> ```

...When I type

```
? address.ToString()
```

...in the command window, the IP Address prints.  Not sure where I'm going wrong.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`address->ToString()` ?